How to fetch token balances from liquidity pool reserve accounts in Solana TokenSwap?
I am currently working on a Solana TokenSwap program and need help understanding how to calculate how much of each token to take away from the pool accounts during liquidity provisioning.
Here is the code I am using:
    const instruction = TokenSwap.depositAllTokenTypesInstruction(
        tokenSwapStateAccount,
        swapAuthority,
        publicKey,
        kryptATA,
        scroogeATA,
        poolKryptAccount,
        poolScroogeAccount,
        poolMint,
        tokenAccountPool,
        TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
        token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        poolTokenAmount * 10 ** poolMintInfo.decimals,
        100e9,
        100e9
    );

I tried to fetch the current balance of each token in the liquidity pool accounts (poolKryptAccount and poolScroogeAccount). I have tried using getTokenAccountBalance, but it only gives me the balance in the user's wallet. How can I fetch the balances of the pool reserve accounts that are part of the TokenSwap program?
What approach should I use to determine the token balances in these reserve accounts and how much to take away from them?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

You need to use getTokenAccountBalance with poolKryptAccount and poolScroogeAccount instead of the user's ATAs.
